# How to set array key that does not exist yet in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

My problem is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'quantity')` when I iterate over response array.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/cart/sync",
    success: function(response){
        let cart = {};
        Object.keys(response).forEach(key => {
            cart[key].quantity = response[key].product_quantity;
            cart[key].discounted_price = response[key].product_discounted_price;
            cart[key].holding = response[key].product_temp_holding;
        });
    }
});
```

I want to make cart[`newKey`] if not exist, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the object if not exist with `cart[key] = cart[key] ? cart[key] : {};`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/cart/sync",
    success: function(response){
        let cart = {};
        Object.keys(response).forEach(key => {
            cart[key] = cart[key] ? cart[key] : {};
            cart[key].quantity = response[key].product_quantity;
            cart[key].discounted_price = response[key].product_discounted_price;
            cart[key].holding = response[key].product_temp_holding;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create the property as an empty object first:

```
cart[key] = {};
```

To do that conditionally, check if it exists first:

```
if (!cart[key]) {
  cart[key] = {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) is for:

> The logical nullish assignment `(x ??= y)` operator only assigns if `x` is
> nullish (`null` or `undefined`).

So you can use it:

```
Object.keys(response).forEach(key => {
    cart[key] ??= {};
    // or similar terms:
    // cart[key] ?? (cart[key] = {});
    // cart[key] || (cart[key] = {});
    cart[key].quantity = response[key].product_quantity;
    cart[key].discounted_price = response[key].product_discounted_price;
    cart[key].holding = response[key].product_temp_holding;
});
```